# DataTables API, fnUpdate not taking value from variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, datatables

The following is code snippet to update two cells of a single row using `fnUpdate` function: (ref:[Datatables](http://datatables.net/api))

```
var oTable = $('#depGridView').dataTable();
oTable.fnUpdate( 'First', 4, 1 );
oTable.fnUpdate( 'Last', 4, 2 );
```

The above code successfully update second and third column of fifth row (:index=4). To get the index value run time , I made the following changes

```
var oTable = $('#depGridView').dataTable();
var getIndex = document.getElementById("indexDepRow").value;
oTable.fnUpdate( 'First', getIndex , 1 );
oTable.fnUpdate( 'Last', getIndex , 2 );
```

but this does not working, it not update my row. To check that the variable **getIndex** storing correct index value, I use **alert(getIndex)** in script. It alert me **4** when I click on fifth row.

How can we overcome this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `parseInt(getIndex)` instead of using row directly.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/sThGk/1/)**

Hope this helps